# Add characters to existing cells with condition R

Tags: r, character, row

I have the following table:

```
structure(list(Id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), stops = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)), .Names = c("Id", "stops"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to add to $stops new characters when the stop did not change but the $Id did.

For example, I would like to get:

```
structure(list(Id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), stops = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "1-1", "1-2", "2"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Id", "stops"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I just would like to do so if the Id is different than the previous one, and if the Stops is the same than the previous one...

I tried with mutate() but it seems I am quite far away to get something working here...

Comment: in row 5 it is `1-2` because it haven't changed for two IDs in a row?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a looples attempt using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, `:=`(stops = as.character(stops), Idindx = rleid(Id))]
indx <- unique(df, by = "Idindx")[, counter := (1:.N) - 1L, by = rleid(stops)]
df[indx[counter > 0], stops := paste(stops, i.counter, sep = "-"), on = "Idindx"]
#    Id stops Idindx
# 1:  a     1      1
# 2:  a     1      1
# 3:  b   1-1      2
# 4:  b   1-1      2
# 5:  a   1-2      3
# 6:  c     2      4
# 7:  c     2      4
# 8:  c     2      4
```

The first step is to create an unique index for each `Id` (as they aren't unique) and convert `stops` to a `character` (per your desired output)

Then, operating on unique indexes identify counts of same `stops` and join back to the original data

Comment: @Floni I've made a small edit which I think is necessary. Also, is it possible that there will be different stops within same `Id`?

Comment: Yes, the Id is actually the name of a place, so there could be different stops in each Id.

Comment: So how would your desired output will look like? Can you edit your example to a more realistic one please?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a loop to solve your problem:

```
# Original data
data <- structure(list(Id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L
), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), stops = c(1, 
                                                       1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)), .Names = c("Id", "stops"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                       -8L), class = "data.frame")

# Add new column, which will be converted in the following loop
data$stops_new <- as.character(data$stops)
new <- 1

for(i in 2:nrow(data)) {

  # Convert values of stops_new, if your specified conditions appear
  if(data$Id[i] != data$Id[i - 1] & data$stops[i] == data$stops[i - 1]) {
    data$stops_new[i] <- paste(data$stops_new[i], "-", new, sep = "")

    # Repeat the convertion for all values with the same ID and stop-value    
    j <- i + 1
    while(data$Id[i] == data$Id[j] & data$stops[i] == data$stops[j]) {
      data$stops_new[j] <- paste(data$stops[i], "-", new, sep = "")
      j <- j + 1
    }

    new <-  new + 1
  }
}

data
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a base R solution.

create indicators showing you whether `Id` has changed (`id.ind`) and whether `stops` has changed (`stops.ind`) from the previous line (convention being that these indicators are set to "0", i.e. no change, for the first row):

```
stops.ind <- c(0, diff(dat$stops))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
id.ind <- c(0, diff(as.numeric(dat$Id)))
```

create new stops vector:

```
stops <- new.stops <- dat$stops
```

row by row check whether a) there is a change in `id` and no change in `stops` or b) there is no change in either from the previous row. in case a) increase `k` by one and append "-k" to `stops` value b) use previous value of `stops`:

```
k <- 0
for(i in 2 : nrow(dat)){
  if(id.ind[i] != 0 & stops.ind[i] == 0){
    k <- k + 1
    new.stops[i] <- paste0(stops[i], "-", k)
  }
   if(id.ind[i] == 0 & stops.ind[i] == 0)
    new.stops[i] <- new.stops[i - 1]
}

new.stops
# [1] "1"   "1"   "1-1" "1-1" "1-2" "2"   "2"   "2"  

new.dat <- data.frame(Id = dat$Id, stops = new.stops)
```